# How to convert 2D bounding box pixel coordinates (x, y, w, h) into relative coordinates (Yolo format)?

Tags: python, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, yolo

Hy! I am annotating image data through an online plateform which is generating output coordinates like this: **bbox":{"top":634,"left":523,"height":103,"width":145}** However, i want to use this annotation to train Yolo. So, I have to convert it in yolo format like this: **4 0.838021 0.605556 0.177083 0.237037**

In this regard, i need help about how to convert it.

Answer (score 4):

Here,
For the size you need to pass the (w,h) and the for the box you need to pass (x,x+w, y, y+h)
https://github.com/ivder/LabelMeYoloConverter/blob/master/convert.py

```
def convert(size, box):
    dw = 1./size[0]
    dh = 1./size[1]
    x = (box[0] + box[1])/2.0
    y = (box[2] + box[3])/2.0
    w = box[1] - box[0]
    h = box[3] - box[2]
    x = x*dw
    w = w*dw
    y = y*dh
    h = h*dh
    return (x,y,w,h)
```

Alternatively, you can use below

```
def convert(x,y,w,h):
 dw = 1.0/w
 dh = 1.0/h
 x = (2*x+w)/2.0
 y = (2*y+w)/2.0
 x = x*dw
 y = y*dh
 w = w*dw
 h = h*dh
 return (x,y,w,h)
```

Each grid cell predicts B bounding boxes as well as C class probabilities. The bounding box prediction has 5 components: (x, y, w, h, confidence). The (x, y) coordinates represent the center of the box, relative to the grid cell location (remember that, if the center of the box does not fall inside the grid cell, than this cell is not responsible for it). These coordinates are normalized to fall between 0 and 1. The (w, h) box dimensions are also normalized to [0, 1], relative to the image size. Let’s look at an example:

[What does the coordinate output of yolo algorithm represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455429/what-does-the-coordinate-output-of-yolo-algorithm-represent)

Comment: Thanks dear @rcvaram for your response. Please need explanation of parameters i.e. w,h.

Comment: Does it mean width and height of image, or bounding box?

Comment: Yes this x and y are center of your bounding box with normalized and w,h are width and height of the bounding box

Comment: I got it. However, i am confused about the following points.
Let me explain.
I have an image of 1920x1080, & i have drawn a bounding box with the following information.
x,y coordinates are 1167, 537px (Coordinates of Top-Left corner of bounding box)
Height: 224px
Width: 320px

With this information, i want to normalize it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Convert bbox dictionary into list with relative coordinates

If you want to convert a python dictionary with the keys `top`, `left`, `widht`, `height`
into a list in the format [`x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`]

Where `x1`, `y1` are the relative coordinates of the `top left corner` of the bounding box and `x2`, `y2` are the relative coordinates of the `bottom right corner` of the bounding box you can use the following function :

```
def bbox_dict_to_list(bbox_dict, image_size):
  h = bbox_dict.get('height')
  l = bbox_dict.get('left')
  t = bbox_dict.get('top')
  w = bbox_dict.get('width')

  img_w, img_h = image_size

  x1 = l/img_w
  y1 = t/img_h
  x2 = (l+w)/img_w
  y2 = (t+h)/img_h
  return [x1, y1, x2, y2]
```

You must pass as arguments the bbox dictionary, and the image size as a tuple -> (image_width, image_height)

Example

```
bbox = {"top":634,"left":523,"height":103,"width":145} 
bbox_dict_to_list(bbox, (1280, 720))
>> [0.40859375, 0.8805555555, 0.521875, 1.02361111111]
```

You can change the return order to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

In order to convert a bounding box to yolo format, **you'll need the image width and the image height**. This is because the yolo format is normalized. Check [albumentation documentation](https://albumentations.ai/docs/getting_started/bounding_boxes_augmentation/#yolo) for a great explanation.

### Fast solution

I developped a light library in python called `bboxconverter` which aims at converting bounding box easily from different formats like coco, yolo or pascal voc. You can check [my repo on github](https://github.com/ODAncona/bboxconverter) for more example, explanations, how-to-guide and tutorials.

You could do the following:

```py
#! pip install bboxconverter #python >= 3.8
from bboxconverter.core.bbox import CWH_BBox, TLWH_BBox

IMAGE_WIDTH = 1920
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 1080

# Create a BBox object
tlwh_bbox = TLWH_BBox(x_min=634,
                      y_min=523,
                      width=103,
                      height=145,
                      image_width=IMAGE_WIDTH,
                      image_height=IMAGE_HEIGHT,
                      class_name='',
                      file_path='')

# Convert to CWH_BBox
cwh_bbox = CWH_BBox.from_TLWH(tlwh_bbox).to_dict()
print(
    f"{cwh_bbox['x_center']}, {cwh_bbox['y_center']}, {cwh_bbox['width']}, {cwh_bbox['height']}"
)
```

For now, the `class_name` and `file_path` must be specified.
For your information :

- CWH means CENTER, WIDTH, HEIGHT
- TLWH means TOP, LEFT, WIDTH, HEIGHT

### Custom Solution

If you still need to implement it yourself for your own purposes. There is a [great article](https://christianbernecker.medium.com/convert-bounding-boxes-from-coco-to-pascal-voc-to-yolo-and-back-660dc6178742) that demonstrate how to convert bounding box from different format. Here is how you could convert from coco(tlwh) to yolo(cwh).

```py
def coco_to_yolo(x1, y1, w, h, image_w, image_h):
    return [((2*x1 + w)/(2*image_w)) , ((2*y1 + h)/(2*image_h)), w/image_w, h/image_h]
```